# How to determine valid Range Header w.r.t HTTP Entity?

Tags: http, http-headers, range

As per HTTP/1.1 spec for Range header (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35), it is stated that

> Byte range specifications in HTTP apply to the sequence of bytes in the entity-body (not necessarily the same as the message-body).

My question is suppose I am requesting to download a binary file of size 1GB & it is having multiple encrypted blocks of 128MB. Since Byte range of HTTP is not equal to the size of file instead the HTTP entity, to download these chunks parallely from the server without breaking the boundaries. Please note that I don't want to reassemble the file. I want to process these blocks separately to decrypt. which Range header would be most suitable & how to derive the correct value to be sent to in that Range header?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range header is applicable for not **full HTTP Entity** rather only the **entity-body** of that HTTP entity. The HTTP Message RFC (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) says

> The message-body (if any) of an HTTP message is used to carry the entity-body associated with the request or response. The message-body differs from the entity-body only when a transfer-coding has been applied, as indicated by the Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41).

Another good reference to read is http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3229.txt (section 4 - The HTTP message-generation sequence) which explains how the HTTP response is generated. Conceptually, when a Range header & transfer encoding both are provided in the request, Range is applied first for message response generation & then the transfer encoding is applied. I think most of the HTTP servers should be confirming to this, so we can apply the range header w.r.t message content length.